# How to detect if a certain user reacts to a message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I have been trying to figure out a way to detect if a certain user reacts to a certain reaction.
I am pretty new to discord.js and have found no way to do it. I have looked through the docs, but nothing came up. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is `message.createReactionCollector()`

The function is documented [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector).

Comment: I know what to use to detect reactions, but I cant find a way to filter who reacted to detect if a certain person reacted to the message.

Comment: Try looking at the `r` value that is passed in the function. You'll likely be able to get the user by doing something like `r.author`. Take a look at the values that `r` has and you'll be able to figure something out.